# Displaying an Array using for loops

Tags: java, arrays, loops, for-loop

I have an array with some set numbers and am looking to display the index and value of each using a for loop.

Here is the array:

```
int[] myArray = {8,4,5,21,7,9,18,2,100};
```

And here is my loop so far, just don't know what to put inside:

```
for(int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++)
```

Comment: System.out.println(i + " : " +myArray[i]);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the value of index `i` using `myArray[i]` in the loop

```
for(int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    System.out.println("index = " + i + ", value = " + myArray[i]);
}
```

Comment: That's great thanks :) I have put it in a different method now. However, I can't seem to call it properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can access each element using `myArray[index]`, for example `myArray[0]` is `8` and `myArray[2]` is `5`.
In your loop `i` will be your index going from `index 0` to `index myArray.length`.